Difference between pytorch timm models for
Pytorch timm model
timm.list_models("*resnet18*", pretrained=True)

outputs
['legacy_seresnet18.in1k',
 'resnet18.a1_in1k',
 'resnet18.a2_in1k',
 'resnet18.a3_in1k',
 'resnet18.fb_ssl_yfcc100m_ft_in1k',
 'resnet18.fb_swsl_ig1b_ft_in1k',
 'resnet18.gluon_in1k',
 'resnet18.tv_in1k',
 'resnet18d.ra2_in1k',
 'skresnet18.ra_in1k']

What is the difference all above? I understand that in1K is ImageNet1K and fb is some facebook's variant of resnet. How should I choose ?
